# sumo - traci start() and close() strange behavior

Tags: python, python-3.6, sumo

Taken from the documentation here [TraCI/Interfacing TraCI from Python](http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/TraCI/Interfacing_TraCI_from_Python)
, I tried to create a simple Python script to open and close Sumo using traci:

```
cfg = os.path.abspath('..\\..\\..\\output\\scenarios\\batch_2018-11-07T085610\\sID_7\\sID_7.sumocfg')
traci.start(['sumo-gui', '-c', cfg])
print(traci.getVersion())
traci.close()
```

1. At `traci.start()` Sumo is launched but the script gets stuck!
2. Adding `--start` flag to the command makes the script continue. But now  `traci.close()` does not close Sumo as it should: [Command 0x7F: Close](http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/TraCI/Control-related_commands#Command_0x7F:_Close).

Is the documentation I'm using completely out of date?

Output of `traci.getVersion()`: `(18, 'SUMO 1.0.1')`

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TraCI documentation refers to the command line version of sumo not to sumo-gui. To get the desired behavior, you need to add `--quit-on-end` to the sumo-gui call.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks.